Doubt with Heat and Potential Energy. (Warning: Many Assumptions)

I had a question in my Textbook which reads as follows,


Before that, we have to assume that the flowing water is ideal.
So, here we have to equate Change in Potential Energy to Heat Energy/Internal Energy. But I don't understand the reasoning behind it.
As 1 answer stated,
$\Delta$KE = 0 if the terrain at the top and the bottom are same. Due to the equation of continuity.
So, then according to Law of Conservation of Energy,
Wnon-conservative = $\Delta$KE + $\Delta$PE
Wnon-conservative = $\Delta$PE
And I am assuming that Wnon-conservative = Heat Energy/Internal Energy
Sorry if I asked too many questions, it is just 1 main question, why heat energy = potential energy in this scenario?

IMHO the question is unclear - what exactly causes the loss of energy? Friction? viscous friction? something else?

In the Niagara Falls example, much of the potential energy is dissipated viscously as internal energy.

@RogerV. Sorry, I was very confused with my doubt that I forgot to mention why I got it in the first place. Yes, friction causes loss of potential energy according to google. I wanted to know why.

@ChetMiller So, viscosity causes heat to be generated?

@ChetMiller but this is kinetic energy, while point 1 speaks about dissipating potential energy.

Most of the potential energy is dissipated to internal energy.  Dnly a fraction  is converted to kinetic energy once it hits the rocks.

@ChetMiller So, if I assume area of the top of the waterfall to be A1 and the bottom to be A2 where the A1 is less than A2. Then, according to the equation of continuity, the change in kinetic energy will be negligible, so we ignore it, so that makes sense.
But what about internal energy and non-conservative work? Is non-conservative work equal to the internal energy/heat dissipated?

No.  There is a substantial increase in kinetic energy of the water between the top of the fall and the bottom.  But most of the kinetic energy is converted to internal energy when the water hits bottom (due to viscous dissipation).  This is manifested in a small increase in the water temperature.

I see, so I'll have to consider viscosity too. Then can I say that?
W(viscosity) + Heat Released = Change in KE + Change in PE
Basically, Law of conservation of energy.

$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=Q-W$

Oh. I see, Thank You!

The Victoria river flows along, falls off a cliff, and continues flowing. The kinetic energy before and after might be equal if the terrain at the top and bottom are similar. Or not. Water currents tend to be vigorous at the bottom of a waterfall. But if you compare the speed of the currents to the speed you would get by dropping water off the cliff without resistance, you might expect that the energy of the currents is small compared to energy from falling off the cliff.
At the top of the cliff, water has some kinetic energy and some internal energy (which you called heat.) This is all kinetic energy of the molecules. The molecules are both flowing together in one direction and moving around randomly bumping into each other.
The kinetic energy gained from falling off the cliff speeds all the water molecules in the same direction. The bulk water flows faster. The water has more kinetic energy.
At the bottom, the water splashes around. The molecules move in many different directions. The total kinetic energy of the molecules is the same as it was as the water landed. But now more of it is in the random motion. The flowing together speed is the same as the top of the cliff.

What I understood: The water has the same translational velocity both at the top and bottom part of the fall, so the potential energy lost must be responsible for the increase in internal energy of the water. SO aren't we implicitly assuming the water flow velocity(assuming water flow is irrotational, incompressible and nonviscous) is constant at the bottom and top of the fall?

I was explicitly assuming the bulk flow is the same at the top and bottom. Or at least that the bulk kinetic energy associated with the bulk flow is small compared to the energy gained by falling off the cliff.

I assume the question is meant to be solved this way: Temperature corresponds to the mean kinetic energy of particles in a substance. So if the water at the bottom of the fall has more kinetic energy (due to it having less potential energy and assuming no losses on its way downward), it should also have higher temperature than the water on top.
The increase in kinetic energy $\Delta E$ equates to the potential energy at the top, so
$$\Delta E = mgh$$
with mass $m$, height $h$ and gravitational acceleration $g = 9.81 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$. The specific heat $c$ of water tells us how much energy is need in order to increase a given mass by $1 \ \mathrm{K}$ (note: as we are dealing with temperature differences, it does not matter whether I use Celsius or Kelvin). So we have
$$c = 4.2 \ \frac{\mathrm{J}}{\mathrm{g} \ \mathrm{K}}$$
And the energy need for an increase of $\Delta T$ is
$$\Delta E = c \cdot m \cdot \Delta T \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \Delta T = \frac{\Delta E}{c \cdot m}$$
Inserting the numbers finally yields
$$\Delta T = \frac{mgh}{cm} = \frac{gh}{c} = \frac{9.81 \ \tfrac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s^2}} \cdot 63 \ \mathrm{m}}{4.2 \ \tfrac{\mathrm{J}}{\mathrm{g} \ \mathrm{K}}} = \frac{9.81 \cdot 63 }{4.2 \times 10^{-3}} \ \mathrm{K} \approx \boxed{0.147 \ \mathrm{K}}$$
which is answer (1).
